# FastICA Implementation.. Matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics, signal-processing

I have been working on a FastICA algorithm implementation using MatLab. Currently the code does not separate the signals as good as id like. I was wondering if anyone here could give me some advice on what I could do to fix this problem?

```
disp('*****Importing Signals*****');

s = [1,30000];

[m1,Fs1] = audioread('OSR_us_000_0034_8k.wav', s);
[f1,Fs2] = audioread('OSR_us_000_0017_8k.wav', s);

ss = size(f1,1);
n = 2; 

disp('*****Mixing Signals*****');

A = randn(n,n); %developing mixing matrix 

x = A*[m1';f1']; %A*x

m_x = sum(x, n)/ss; %mean of x 

xx = x - repmat(m_x, 1, ss); %centering the matrix 

c = cov(x');
sq = inv(sqrtm(c)); %whitening the data 
x = c*xx;

D = diff(tanh(x)); %setting up newtons method 
SD = diff(D);

disp('*****Generating Weighted Matrix*****');

w = randn(n,1); %Random weight vector
w = w/norm(w,2); %unit vector
w0 = randn(n,1);
w0 = w0/norm(w0,2); %unit vector

disp('*****Unmixing Signals*****');

while abs(abs(w0'*w)-1) > size(w,1)

   w0 = w;
   w = x*D(w'*x) - sum(SD'*(w'*x))*w;  %perform ICA
   w = w/norm(w, 2);

end

disp('*****Output After ICA*****');

sound(w'*x); % Supposed to be one of the original signals

subplot(4,1,1);plot(m1); title('Original Male Voice'); 
subplot(4,1,2);plot(f1); title('Original Female Voice'); 
subplot(4,1,4);plot(w'*x); title('Post ICA: Estimated Signal');

%figure;
%plot(z); title('Random Mixed Signal');

%figure;
%plot(100*(w'*x)); title('Post ICA: Estimated Signal');
```

Comment: " the code does not separate the signals as good as id like" what does that mean? How do you expect anyone to help you with so little information? You should read [ask] and [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). And additionally you should add information about the desired output and what the problem with the current output is...

Answer (score 0):

Your covariance matrix c is 2 by 2, you cannot work with that. You have to mix your signal multiple times with random numbers to get anywhere, because you must have some signal (m1) common to different channels. I was unable to follow through your code for fast-ICA but here is a PCA example:

```
url = {'https://www.voiptroubleshooter.com/open_speech/american/OSR_us_000_0034_8k.wav';...
    'https://www.voiptroubleshooter.com/open_speech/american/OSR_us_000_0017_8k.wav'};
%fs = 8000;
m1 = webread(url{1});
m1 = m1(1:30000);
f1 = webread(url{2});
f1 = f1(1:30000);
ss = size(f1,1);
n = 2; 
disp('*****Mixing Signals*****');
A = randn(50,n); %developing mixing matrix 
x = A*[m1';f1']; %A*x
[www,comp] = pca(x');
sound(comp(:,1)',8000)
```